# Returning a dynamic C style string from a function?

Tags: c++, winapi, function, c-strings

Basically I have a function that roughly looks like this and I need to return out.

```
const char* UTF16ToUTF8(const wchar_t *in) {
    int tmp = wcslen(in);
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &in[0], (size_t)tmp, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::vector<char> out;
    out.resize(size_needed);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0,  &in[0], (size_t)tmp, &out[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);

    return &out[0];
}
```

Obviously out gets dereferenced when returning. What are my options? I need to be able to call this function like so. I would absolutely love to stay on the stack.

```
utf8outputfile << UTF16ToUTF8(wchar_tString) << endl;
fprintf(utf8outputfile, "%s", UTF16ToUTF8(L"Mmm Mmm Unicode String κόσμε"));
return UTF16ToUTF8(wchar_tString);
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with `std::vecor`. Is passing `&out[0]` to the `WideCharToMultiByte` to multibyte safe? Good form?

Comment: @Sodved no - it will blow up because the vector will be destructed (and backing allocation freed) when the function returns. thus, the result of this function will never point to an valid allocation. if the vector were to outlive the function, then you could certainly use a char vector to represent a string (although std::string is more appropriate in the majority of cases).

Comment: @Sodved however, vector does guarantee a contiguous allocation. treating `&vec[0]` as a c array is fine.

Comment: @Justin Thanks mate. I knew it was a bogus return, but nice to know you can use `&vec[0]` as a output param to old style function. Learn something new every day. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't trouble yourself with any such worries and return an `std::string`:

```
std::string UTF16ToUTF8(const wchar_t *in) {
  std::vector<char> out;
  //...
  return std::string(out.begin(), out.end());  // or std::string(out.data())
}
```

Then, in your C interface, use:

```
printf("%s", UTF16ToUTF8(ws).c_str());
```

I would even make the argument of the function `std::wstring` and extract the C-string only when calling the API function.

The `begin/end` version includes *all* characters, the `.data()` version treats the buffer as a null-terminated string. Pick whichever is most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Returning std::string would be my first choice.

However if you absolutely, positively need a char*, you have several options.

You could allocate a new char* on the heap and return that, being really, *really* careful to make sure that the caller *always* deallocates the memory.  I believe there is a boost auto_ptr equivalent that is array friendly that would make explicit this ownership transfer.

Another option is for the caller to pass in the char* (and max size), and the function to put data in there.  Thus the caller always owns the memory.

Another option is for the caller to pass in a char** (or char*&), and your function allocates memory to the caller's pointer.  This makes the ownership transfer explicit.  (you could also have a size (size_t&) parameter to hold the size, if it's something the caller is likely to need).

Comment: I am probably going to go with std::string.

The char*& thing is interesting though. Could it be allocated on the stack? I wouldn't mind having to ditch the return value if I could do it all on the stack with a single call to the function.